How can I improve cabling coming through a wall to a car charger?
3 years ago I hastily installed a wall charger in my garage with 6/3 cable and didn’t try hard enough to find a good solution to make the cable look good coming out of the drywall. Now I’m trying to fix it and I found this solution and was wondering if I should do anything differently or just follow that solution completely.


Aside from that, there's also the code violation of running 6/3 NM cable at 48A actual charge / 60A breaker.   Re-run the commissioning procedure on instructions p. 28 and set to 40A actual.  The 60A breaker is legal on 55A wire because 240.4(B), but you are required to treat it like a 55A breaker and only draw <=44A.

It isn't just about "looking good". You have code violations here. The cable must be protected and secured.
One option would be to simply mount a conduit body over the penetration, and extend from it with rigid or flexible conduit to the charger base. I assume that there's a port on the bottom of the unit to which you can connect a threaded conduit termination. You'll need at least 3/4" conduit for a cable of this size.

I don't believe in-wall junction boxes as in the linked answer are needed or appropriate.
